# Node.js - passing variable to multiple functions within async.parallel

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, asynchronous

I have a set of functions that get dynamically loaded. Each function is in its own file and looks like:

```
module.exports = function(incomingData, done) {
    var test = incomingData + " foo -->"
    done(null, test);
};
```

These are loaded in to an object ('allPluggins') that then looks like:

```
{ 'test-bar': [Function], 'test-foo': [Function] }
```

I wish to execute all functions using async.parallel passing the same 'incomingData' variable to each.

So far I have:

```
async.parallel(allPluggins, done());
```

Can anyone advise how I can call async.parallel passing in the same 'incomingData' variable to each function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap each function or `bind()` each one. Examples:

Using wrapper functions:

```
var incomingData = 'hello world';

Object.keys(allPluggins).forEach(function(key) {
  var fn = allPluggins[key];
  allPluggins[key] = function(done) {
    fn(incomingData, done);
  };
});

async.parallel(allPluggins, done);
```

Using `bind()`:

```
var incomingData = 'hello world';

var key;
for (key in allPluggins)
  allPluggins[key] = allPluggins[key].bind(undefined, incomingData);

async.parallel(allPluggins, done);
```